# How to manipulate ContentPlaceHolder Content from a MasterPage

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I want to edit the contents of ContentPlaceHolder from the code behind of the masterpage, please help me, you can assume any masterpage with any content placeholder.

All answers would be respected.

Comment: I would rather say its against the master-content. could you explain why would you need that?

Answer (score 3):

If the content changes are trivial and cosmetic, consider client-side manipulation e.g. jQuery.

Otherwise, you *could* use FindControl() over the `Controls` collection of the ContentPlaceHolder, but that's fraught and messy.

A neater solution is to take advantage of [Polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming). The calling page is available from the MasterPage's `Page` property.

So: if you have an interface like so:

```
public interface IContentInjectable
{
    Literal ExposedLiteral { get; }
}
```

And your page template is implemented like so:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPages/Test.master" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="TestPage" Codebehind="TestPage.aspx.cs" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="phContent" Runat="Server">

    <asp:Literal ID="litTest" runat="server" />

</asp:Content>
```

With code-behind like:

```
public partial class TestPage : System.Web.UI.Page, IContentInjectable
{
    public Literal ExposedLiteral
    {
        get
        {
            return litTest;
        }
    }
}
```

Your Masterpage code-behind could be like this:

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);

    IContentInjectable icPage = this.Page as IContentInjectable;
    if (icPage != null)
    {
        icPage.ExposedLiteral.Text = "Test Text";
    }
}
```

Comment: That seems like a lot of extra code when find control is one line. A pain to write, but maybe not so compared to the interface and etc.